# What does $ \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i(i-1)!}$ converge to?

Tags: convergence-divergence

What does $ \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i(i-1)!}$ converge to?

That is $1 +  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3*2!} + ... + \frac{1}{n(n-1)!}$

Comment: Hint : $i(i-1)!=i!$

Comment: Hint 2: Exp...${}$

Comment: According to this website : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial , it is $e$

Comment: as you do not include $0!$ it is $e-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

For any $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$, $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\dots.$$

So you can consider $e^1=?$